# Block remote CVS users from physically logging in to repo server

Tags: ssh, cvs

Our users are using ssh shell to run all CVS actitivies. Is it possible to block them from physically logging to the CVS server? For example, they use the following command to checkout files:

```
cvs -z3 -d:ext:username@cvsserver:/cvsroot/projects checkout -d project1 .
```

Since they are part of the group having the permissions to read/write CVS repository file system on the server, they could SSH login to the repo server and delete physical files. Can I block them? I have tried to sshd_config with DeneyUsers, or set /etc/passwd with NOLOGON shell, but they all block CVS commands too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  I'm using a custom shell that executes cvs only.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (getenv("CVSROOT") == NULL)
    setenv("CVSROOT", "/home/cvs", 0);

    execl("/usr/bin/cvs", "cvs", "server", NULL);

    printf("No Permission.\n"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could install `rssh` and set this as the user's login shell.

http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/

rssh has a list of commands (including `cvs`) that you can restrict users to. If they try and ssh directly into the machine they will be denied and receive a message like this:

```
This account is restricted by rssh.
Allowed commands: cvs 

If you believe this is in error, please contact your system administrator.
```